# Moving Symfony from development to production

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, production

I have made some web sites using **Symfony 4** that work using the PHP server on my local machine.

When I FTP the Symfony `project-directory` to my *1and1* Linux web host I can not get the web sites to show up in my browser. I have tried to implement the guidelines on the Symfony documentation for doing this.

In the example below I used the symfony-demo project. I did the following:

```
composer create-project symfony/symfony-demo
```

this looked fine on my browser running on the PHP server on my local machine.

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

Edited `.env`: `APP_ENV=dev` to `APP_ENV=prod`. Added the code from **Apache** with `mod_php/PHP-CGI` on Symfony website to `.htaccess`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    // etc etc
</VirtualHost>
```

Used FileZilla to upload `symfony-dir` (*over 11000 files*) to *1and1* server

Looked at `www.my-web-sites/symfony-demo`

I just get a page with adverts which is what happens when there is nothing there.

The `symfony-demo` directory is there and has files in it according to *FileZilla*

I know I am quite a long way from understanding this and there may be several issues I need to address but googling and reading the documentation does not seem to be taking me forward at this point. Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Useful lesson on correct formatting of post

Comment: the index file of the symfony4 project lives in **<symfony directory>/public/index.php**  , i did not had any experience with your hosting provider, but it would be better if you had SSH access and instead of uploading every single file from your dependencies you ocould just upload the composer.json and install the dependencies. So if you want to access your symfony project with the URL **www.my-web-sites/symfony-demo** , you must rewrite the real path **www.my-web-sites/symfony-demo/public** to **www.my-web-sites/symfony-demo**

Comment: there are so many possible reasons, but there are some good manuals for deploying symfony apps. for example https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-symfony-application-to-production-on-ubuntu-14-04 maybe there you can find a solution